# what is the correct order to read SQL where function

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

The goal is to select sales person who did not have any orders related to the company with the name 'Red'

My question is in the second select (within the where function) why the code didn't include 'from salesperson S'? I am confused since in the second select s.name I didn't define the 's'

what is the proper order for me to read the attached code?

```
SELECT  s.name
FROM    salesperson s
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  s.name 
    FROM    company c, orders o # why not include salesperson s at here ? 
    WHERE   s.sales_id = o.sales_id 
        AND c.com_id = o.com_id
        AND c.name = 'RED'
    );
```

Input:

SalesPerson table:

| sales_id | name | salary | commission_rate | hire_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 100000 | 6 | 4/1/2006 |
| 2 | Amy | 12000 | 5 | 5/1/2010 |
| 3 | Mark | 65000 | 12 | 12/25/2008 |
| 4 | Pam | 25000 | 25 | 1/1/2005 |
| 5 | Alex | 5000 | 10 | 2/3/2007 |

Company table:

| com_id | name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RED | Boston |
| 2 | ORANGE | New York |
| 3 | YELLOW | Boston |
| 4 | GREEN | Austin |

Orders table:

| order_id | order_date | com_id | sales_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2014 | 3 | 4 | 10000 |
| 2 | 2/1/2014 | 4 | 5 | 5000 |
| 3 | 3/1/2014 | 1 | 1 | 50000 |
| 4 | 4/1/2014 | 1 | 4 | 25000 |

Output:

| name |
| --- |
| Amy |
| Mark |
| Alex |

Comment: read up on correlated subquery

Comment: `FROM    company c, orders ` <<-- why not use a JOIN?

Comment: yeah, I can use the join function.   However, I just don't understand what is the proper order to read the first solution I posted.

Comment: I'd suggest to read this: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: @MaciejLos: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/

Comment: A correlated subquery (like your second select) already has access to the 'current-row' of the main query (your first select). In fact, the subquery is performed once for each row of the main query  (logically speaking). Therefore you don't need to join to the main table again. 's.name' in the subquery select is a 'dummy' entry; it is not used, because the subquery merely checks the presence of a record (EXISTS) satisfying its WHERE condition; you could easily use SELECT 1 or SELECT * (some may have performance implications depending on the rdbms product)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for pointing that out. In my opinion, the way of presenting/explaining join's is no matter as long as OP is able to understand that piece of information then use it in reality.